# Compartir texto por instagram Direct en Swift

Tags: ios, swift, instagram

Quiero encontrar la manera de compartir texto desde la app a instagram Direct, solo me crea un post y me pide una imagen para compartir en el Feed de instagram y no enviar por instagram Direct

Comment: Si en la documentación de la API de Instagram no existencia alguna referencia sobre eso, entonces deberías esperar a que la implementen sino no se podría.

Comment: tienes una manera de ir directamente porque he buscado y no me aparece algo especifico